# Trigger to update

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

In advance izvenyayus for the dirt in the code but a friend can not,in General, there is a trigger

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Trigger [dbo].[Need] 
ON [dbo].[Bill of materials]
FOR INSERT 
AS 
    Declare @a int;
    Declare @b int;
    Declare @C int;
    Declare @v int;
    Declare @q int;

    select @C = Material @v = the Quantity in stock from Vedomostithe 

    select @a = sum(amount) 
    from Bid 
    where Status = 'In transit' 
      and Application.Part name = @Name 
    group by details 

    select @b = number 
    from the Plan 
    where the Plan.ID = @from 

    select @q = Name parts 
    from the arrival Journal

    update Bill of materials 
    set a = @b - isnull(@a, 0) - @v 
    where the Bill of materials .Material = @q
```

his task is to calculate the Net profit by the simple formula

```
Net demand = Number plan - number (only those which more on the way) - quantity in stock
```

Here is the problem, when the Net demand must be zero, it takes the value net need other parts

Comment: Unless you're using a weird edition of SQL Server which is licensed on a per-character basis, please consider using longer, more meaningful variable names. Also, a trigger that makes no reference to either [inserted or deleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191300.aspx) tends to set off alarm bells since it means the trigger is completely ignorant of *what* data has changed in the table.

Comment: Automatic translation of **code** has completely ruined it. Better see it on [Stack Overflow на русском — Триггер на обновление](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522576/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)